# Move icon up and inline with my main heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move around with my main icon in the top, which is placed in the navbar. I'm using bootstrap and a normal css file called "Site.css"

In my masterpage i i'm getting the files down by these:

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Some code:**

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">M-Hotels&nbsp;
                <div class="IconFront">
                    <asp:Image class="img1" ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="28px" ImageUrl="~/Icon.png" Width="30px" ImageAlign="Right" />
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Well, right now the icon is inline with the heading. I just want to move the icon up a little, but can't seem too do it.

**Have tried with the CSS in the Site.css file:**

```
IconFront {
position:absolute; 
}

img1 {
position:relative; 
top:10px; 
left:0px; 
}
```

But with this, nothing is happening.. it just wont move :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the class with wrong selector syntax. Add a dot to the selector.

```
.IconFront {
  position:absolute; 
}

.img1 {
  position:relative; 
  top:10px; 
  left:0px; 
}
```

Comment: baah.. sometimes the smallest error is causing problems haha .. didn't saw that :D

Comment: It happens to all of us, Mikkel :)